# Bluetooth vulnerability on a Raspberry PI running Raspian

Tags: linux, exploit, vulnerability, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Is it possible for someone to exploit a Raspberry PI running Raspian through bluetooth just by having the bluetooth enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be vulnerable, and possibly exploited. Whether or not something is *presently* and publicly vulnerable, your guess/Google search ability is as good as mine.

If there was a current, widely known issue, most likely it would be already fixed or there would be an ongoing rush to fix it.